# How to get rating value when rate in function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { Rating } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class Test extends React.Component {

  CheckRating = (rating) => {
    alert(rating)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Rating icon='heart' defaultRating={1} maxRating={5} onRate={() => this.CheckRating(rating)} />
    )
  }
}
export default Test
```

here i am using semantic-ui-react for rating.
How can i get value of rating in  CheckRating() function.
I tried with event.target.value  anbd it is coming undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the event in the onRate handler. Using the point free notation should be enough:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Rating } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class Test extends React.Component {

  CheckRating = (event, data) => {
    alert(data.rating)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <Rating icon='heart' defaultRating={1} maxRating={5} onRate={this.CheckRating} />
    )
  }
}
export default Test
```

Comment: It is coming undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code.

```
CheckRating = (e, { rating }) => {
    alert(rating)
}

render(){
    return (
        <Rating icon='heart' defaultRating={1} maxRating={5} onRate={ this.CheckRating } />
    )
}
```

The thing is you must to obtain the rating values from the event object fired when the user rate!

You can find more information on this example from [React Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/rating/#types-on-rate)